# Iterate over multiple arrays to perform tasks?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I have 9 arrays that contain 19 values each.

Lets say they are `a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9` (each a1,a2...a9 contain 19 values each) and let's call them ***`a` arrays.***

I have 9 more arrays that contain 19 values each.

Let's say they are `b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9` (each b1,b2...b9 contain 19 values each) and let's call them ***`b` arrays.***

I would now like to take the **first value of each of the** ***`a` arrays*** and the **first value of each of the** ***`b` arrays***, divide them `(a/b)`, which will give me a new array, let's say `a/b` with 19 values. Then I calculate the standard deviation of these 19 values using `numpy.std`.

I then want to iterate again over these arrays, but **this time the second values of each of these arrays** and so on until the last (19th) value and perform the above operation.

If I only had 2 arrays (say `a1` and `b1`) I could use `zip` like:

```
div_array = [] # The empty array that will have the divided values
for a,b in zip(a1,b1):
    div = a/b
    div_array.append(div)

std = np.std(div_array)
```

**How do I repeat the above in my lengthy case??**

**EDIT:**

I finally **need 19 different standard deviations,** i.e. I calculate it for the first values, then the second values and so on..

Comment: you don't like `for i in range(0, length(a)): do a[i]` syntax. Do you?

Comment: @deathangel908: So `a` here refers to an array containing all my `a1,a2...a9`?

Comment: yep, I would just use current element index. `a[i], b[i], c[i]` etc. But maybe there's a better way.

Comment: But then I would need to create 9 empty arrays that would contain my divided values after which I calculate the stddev for each of them like I have shown in the example?

Comment: You specified that you already have arrays. Why would you need to create new ones?

Comment: I meant for the `div_array` part.. I finally need 19 standard deviations for the 19 different `bins` lets say..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the power of `numpy` for division if you are using it for `std`?

```
>>> # You can create these array in a loop if you want
>>> a = np.array([a1, a2, a3, ..., a9])
>>> b = np.array([b1, b2, b3, ..., b9]) 
>>> c = np.std(a / b, 0)
```

Example (with details about `np.std`):

```
>>> a1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a2 = np.array([2, 3, 4])
>>> a  = np.array([a1, a2])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])
>>> b1 = np.array([10, 100, 1000])
>>> b2 = np.array([20, 200, 2000])
>>> b  = np.array([b1, b2])
>>> b
array([[10, 100, 1000], 
       [20, 200, 2000]])
>>> a/b
array([[0.1,  0.02, 0.003],
       [0.1, 0.015, 0.002]])
>>> np.std(a/b)             # The standard deviation of the whole matrix
0.04289... 
>>> np.std(a/b, 0)          # The standard deviation of each column
array([0, 0.0025, 0.0005])
>>> np.std(a/b, 1)          # The standard deviation of each row
array([0.04229263, 0.04345879])
```

Comment: I finally need 19 different standard deviations, i.e. I calculate it for the first values, then the second values and so on.. The above seems to give me 1 standard deviation. Can you explain what the `0` stands for in `c = np.std(a / b, 0)` ?

Comment: It's the axis over which the standard deviation is calculated. Axes are defined for arrays with more than one dimension. A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

Comment: @ThePredator The above gives you `19` different standard deviations, check the shape of `c`.

Comment: @Holt, I believe you are right! So these 19 standard deviations are those of `a/b` right? But I would like to know how does `np.std(a/b,0)` iterates taking the first values, then the second values and so on?

Comment: @ThePredator `a` and `b` are `9x19` matrix with value `a_ij` and `b_ij`. `a/b` gives you a matrix `t` where for every `i` and `j` `t_ij = a_ij / b_ij`. It is the numpy way of dividing every elements in two matrix. Once you have your `t` matrix (`9x19`), the `std` function gives you the standard deviation on every column (as well explained by Matt).

Answer (score 0):

You could have each `a` and `b` array in another array. So it would be

`a[0] = a1`, `a[1] = a2`, etc. same thing for `b`

Then something like:

```
for i in range(length(a)):
    div_array = []
    for j in range(length(a[i])):
        div = a[i][j]/b[i][j]
        div_array.append(div)

    std.append(np.std(div_array))
```

Then you have an array `std` with all the values you want.

Of course, that would work if `a` and `b` are the same length and `a[0]` and `b[0]` and so on are the same length also. Which is true in your case.

Comment: I would like to have the standard deviations for each of the 19 values separately. Does the above do that? I can see that we append all the` div_array` into one list `std`

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake, you have to empty the `div_array` I just fixed that now. I haven't tested it, but you could try it, it should be fast to check, right?

Comment: Well it still doesn't do what I need!

Answer (score 0):

So a while back I wrote a class that essentially does what you're asking for. The only trick is that you'll have to pass the class a list of iterators for each array.

`column_iter_traversal.py`

```
"""
This code will take in a iterator of iterators. You can view the first
iterator as the rows of a graph (a matrix being a specific case of graphs)
and each iterable giving you the columns (or nodes) of that graph.

so if you have a graph
[[1, 2],
[3],
[4, 5]]

we'd expect the iterator to return [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]
"""

class ColumnTraversalIter():
    """
    This is a class which is used to contain the currently travered state.
    This is the class which defines the returned object for
    column_traversal_iter. The iter that function returns is an instance of
    this class.
    """
    def __init__(self, iter_of_iters):
        # Build a list of iterators
        self.iter_list = []
        for it in iter_of_iters:
            self.iter_list.append(it)
        self.current_iter_index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        # Get the next value from the current iterator
        try:
            return_val = next(self.iter_list[self.current_iter_index])
            self.current_iter_index = self._increment_index(
                self.current_iter_index,
                len(self.iter_list))
            return return_val
        except StopIteration:
            # When we run into a stop iteration we know that the current
            # iterator is out of values. Remove the current iterator from
            # the iterator list.
            del self.iter_list[self.current_iter_index]
            # If we are out of iterators it's time to raise StopIteration
            if len(self.iter_list) == 0:
                raise StopIteration
            else:
                # Otherwise, set the current_iter_index and recall next
                self.current_iter_index = self._increment_index(
                    self.current_iter_index,
                    len(self.iter_list))
                return self.__next__()
        except IndexError:
            # Someone called __next__ when there aren't any iterators left in
            # the iter_list.
            raise StopIteration

    @staticmethod
    def _increment_index(iter_index, wrap_length):
        if iter_index + 1 > wrap_length:
            print("returning 0")
            return 0
        else:
            print("returning {}".format(iter_index + 1))
            return iter_index + 1

def column_traversal_iter(iter_of_iters):
    """

    args:
        iterator: a iterator of iterators. If there aren't any iterators or
                  there are non iterator elements this will explode.
    returns a COlumnTraversalIter
    """
    return ColumnTraversalIter(iter_of_iters)
```

`tests.py`

```
import unittest
from column_traversal import column_traversal_iter

class TestBruteforceImplemetation(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_no_iters(self):
        test_iter = iter([])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_of_one_empty_iter(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_of_many_empty_iter(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([]), iter([]), iter([])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_simple_one_by_one_matrix(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([1]), iter([2]), iter([3])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        expected_traversal = [1, 2, 3]
        for actual_value, expected_value in zip(column_iter, expected_traversal):
            self.assertEqual(actual_value, expected_value)

        # Check to make sure there's a stop iteration.
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_simple_jagged_graph(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([1]), iter([2, 4]), iter([3])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        expected_traversal = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        for actual_value, expected_value in zip(column_iter, expected_traversal):
            self.assertEqual(actual_value, expected_value)

        # Check to make sure there's a stop iteration.
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_simple_two_by_two_matrix(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([1, 4]), iter([2, 5]), iter([3, 6])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        expected_traversal = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        for actual_value, expected_value in zip(column_iter, expected_traversal):
            self.assertEqual(actual_value, expected_value)

        # Check to make sure there's a stop iteration.
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)

    def test_iter_one_iter_is_blank(self):
        """
        One empty iter and many empty iters should hit one stop iteration.
        """
        test_iter = iter([iter([1, 3]), iter([2, 4]), iter([])])
        column_iter = column_traversal_iter(test_iter)
        expected_traversal = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        for actual_value, expected_value in zip(column_iter, expected_traversal):
            self.assertEqual(actual_value, expected_value)

        # Check to make sure there's a stop iteration.
        with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
            next(column_iter)
```

And you'd use this code by

```
divisor_iter_list = []
for a_list in a_lists:
    divisor_iter_list.append(iter(a_list))

dividend_iter_list = []
for b_list in b_lists:
    divident_iter_list.append(iter(b_list))


divisor_iter = ColumnTraversalIter(divisor_iter_list)
dividend_iter = ColumnTraversalIter(divident_iter_list)
for divisor, dividend in zip(divisor_iter, dividend_iter):
    # Do calculations.
```